# Function to Reply a specific index value

Tags: prolog

I want a Function to enter X, Y for a particular object and then give me a value in this X and Y.

value(X,Y):-return saved value in(X,Y).

Comment: This is difficult to understand. How are you going to use this?

Comment: indexof(X,Y):-cell(X,Y,Num),write(Num).

Comment: You need an extra argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your *predicate* to "return" something, remember that this is not a function and it does not have a return value. The only "return value" of a predicate is success or failure.

You can add an extra argument to your predicate, but in the example you give this is silly: you already have a predicate `cell(X, Y, Value)`, if I am reading this correctly.